# Cannot make JPanel components show

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jcomponent

I have this class, `Carta`, that I use to draw a card. The paint method works well on itself:

```java
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    RoundRectangle2D rect2 = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(posicio.x + CARD_WIDTH + 20,
                                                         (posicio.y * CARD_HEIGHT) + 10,
                                                         CARD_WIDTH,
                                                         CARD_HEIGHT,
                                                         CORNER_ANGLE,
                                                         CORNER_ANGLE);
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fill(rect2);
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.draw(rect2);
    BufferedImage imatge = null;
    if (caraAmunt) {
        try {
            imatge = ImageIO.read(new File(cami));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Carta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            imatge = ImageIO.read(new File(camiDefecte));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Carta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    g.drawImage(imatge.getScaledInstance(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH),
                posicio.x + CARD_WIDTH + 20,
                (posicio.y * CARD_HEIGHT) + 10,
                null);
}
```

The problem I have is when trying to get to paint it on a `JPanel`. This is part of a larger GUI that contains a `JPanel` with a deck of these Cards. When I add them to the `JPanel` I see nothing on screen. I am instantiating a `JFrame` in which I have the `JPanel` to which I add every Card. How can I paint them inside this `JPanel`, say `JPanel foo`?

Example code

```java
Carta foo = new Carta(SPADES, ACE, new Point(0, 0), true);
this.add(foo);
```

Comment: If I instantiate it directly on the JFrame works well

Comment: The above comment should be added to your question. Information about the question should be found in one place.

Comment: 1) Don't do I/O in a painting method. The painting method should be efficient. The images should be read in your constructor. 2) Your class doesn't have a preferred size. When you add the component directly to the frame, the component is given all the space available to the frame. When you add the component to a panel first, the panel respects the preferred size which you haven't set, so there is no room to paint your image. You need to override the `getPreferredSize(...)` method to return the size.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I question whether you know what you're doing, in having a component override paintComponent just to show an image. In decades of swing programming I never felt the need to write a component that overrides paintComponent. This is for people who want to write custom widgets that draw pixels and stuff in a way that no existing components can. But just to draw some images? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem. I was painting inside the class and that did not make sense. Thanks for the replies :)